# Filtered related list in Salesforce

Tags: related-list, filters

How to get a filtered related list in Salesforce? I know that we can get a custom Related List using PageBlock Table in a VF page but i don't know how to get hyperlinks around records in related lists and actions like Edit/Delete like a standard one. Below i have posted screenshots of both related lists..1st is Native Saleforce Related List and 2nd is custom one. How to make custom related list look like the Standard one? Help!!!!

[image: Standard Salesforce Related List which has links to records and actions as well(edit/del)]

[image: Custom (filtered) related list using a table in VF page but without links to the records(apart from Account) and no actions.]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many variations to the solution but here is one I've used (you could use CSS better than the nbsp; and the hardcoded styles - I just grabbed this from some existing VF page in my org)

```
<apex:form>
 ...
<apex:outputPanel id="oppoRelatedList">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!givingOpportunities}" var="o">
 <apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header"><apex:outputText value="Action"/></apex:facet>
    <apex:outputLink title="" value="/{!o.id}/e?retURL=/{!o.id}" 
        style="font-weight: normal; color: rgb(35,111,189); text-decoration: none">Edit
    </apex:outputLink>   
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) deleteOppo('{!o.Id}');" 
         style="font-weight: normal; color: rgb(35,111,189); text-decoration: none">Del</a>
 </apex:column>

 <apex:column headerValue="Name">
    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.View,o.id)}">{!o.name}</apex:outputLink> 
 </apex:column>
 <apex:column value="{!o.otherField1}"/>
 <apex:column value="{!o.otherField2}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable> 

 <!--  actionFunctions must be within apex:form tabs -->
 apex:actionFunction action="{!deleteOppo}" name="deleteOppo" reRender="oppoRelatedList, pageMsgs" >        
  <apex:param name="oppoid" value="" assignTo="{!selectedOppoId}"/>
 </apex:actionFunction>
...
 </apex:form>
```

You'll need a controller that

a) returns the list of related Opportunities in a getter for `givingOpportunities`

b) has a setter for the `selectedOppoId` to be deleted

c) has an Action Method `deleteOppo` that deletes the Opportunity that is something like this

```
    public  ID      selectedOppoId                  {get; set;}

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ACTION METHOD    - deleteOppo
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public PageReference deleteOppo() {
        PageReference resPg;
        if (this.selectedOppoId != null) 
            try {delete new Opportunity(id = this.selectedOppoId);}
            catch (Exception e) {ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,' Delete of Opportunity failed, reason: ',e));
            }
        return resPg;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks@crop1645. This is awesome..Really helpful. I have written a controller for returning list of related opportunities. But i have no idea how to write the method for deleting(deleteOpp) the records. I am quite new to apex and VF. Can you please share the related sample code?? Thanks, Ankit

Comment: Ankit - I added the method to the answer